# in VBA, what does a multilevel parent/Child loop look like?

Tags: excel, vba

I am extracting items from a database into excel. The items is the start and each has multi levels of parent / child /child of Child/ etc /etc that look like this.

```
Item1
  Parent
    Child
    Child
  Parent
    Child
      ChildChild
       ChildChildChild
  Parent
    etc
Item2
  etc. etc.
```

Perhaps the biggest item has 6 or 7 levels deep. It could be worth noting also that the Items, Parents and Child come from the same table each with a unique ID.

I was just wondering how the structure of looping should be?
Can I tell VBA to look into infinite levels and stop when there is no more? 
Do I need to specify the maximum number of levels? 
Would I have two or more functions exchanging the variables so that i extract from the same tables?

I just cannot get my head around what seems to be a simple issue.

I tried to create an item sub and two functions
like this code

```
Public Sub cascade()
CurrentDb.Open
  'strSQL0 = 'some string
With rs0
    .Source = "Select the item....."
End With
rsCount0 = rs0.RecordCount 'Parents Level0
For i = 1 To rsCount0
    If Not rs0.EOF Then
        'Input the extracted data of Item (i=1)
    Else
    End If
'After putting item(i) Description, look for next level in getSxMaksPar.
    ItemIDP = rs0.Fields(2).Value
    ItemPQty = 1
    getSxMaksPar j, ItemIDP, ItemPQty
rs0.MoveNext
Next 'i
MsgBox ("Load Seradex data completed.")
End Sub 'cascade()
'Parent sub
Public Sub getSxMaksPar(j As Integer, ItemIDP As Long, ItemPQty As Long)
CurrentDb.Open
With rsMaksPar
    .Source = "SELECT the itemIDP in the next record "
    .Open
End With

rsCountPar = rsMaksPar.RecordCount
If rsCountPar = 0 Then Exit Sub
For j = 1 To rsCountPar
    If Not rsMaksPar.EOF Then
        'Input the extracted data of Item (j=1)
            ItemIDC = rsMaksPar.Fields(2).Value
            ItemCQty = rsMaksPar.Fields(5).Value
        ' Get the Child of the parent.
            getSxMaksChild j, ItemIDC, ItemCQty
    Else
    End If
rsMaksPar.MoveNext
Next ' j
End Sub
'Child sub
Public Sub getSxMaksChild(j As Integer, ItemIDC As Long, ItemCQty As Long)
CurrentDb.Open
With rsMaksChild
  .Source = "SELECT "
  .Open
End With
rsCountChild = rsMaksChild.RecordCount
If rsCountChild = 0 Then Exit Sub

For k = 1 To rsCountChild
    If Not rsMaksChild.EOF Then
        'Input the extracted data of Item (k=1)
            ItemIDP = rsMaksChild.Fields(2).Value
            ItemCQty = rsMaksChild.Fields(5).Value
            getSxMaksPar j, ItemIDP, ItemPQty
    Else
    End If
rsMaksChild.MoveNext
Next ' k
End Sub
```

Comment: This is pretty vague and as shown there isn't really a good solution.  Can you provide sample data representative of what you're actually working with, along with expected results?  And if you have any additional code you've tried other than the pseudo-code provided, please add that to the question as well.

Comment: Vaguely looks like you may be looking for a [recursive function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/recursive-procedures)

Comment: tigeravatar. I've added some code. Thank you.